# Central limit theorem and exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning

I am currently studying a course in statistics and probability. Due to current restrictions alot of the education is online.

There is an assigment a check that we understand the basic theory, in which we are supposed to pair up random varibles with the right approximative distridution using th central limit theory.
The assignment reads:

"36 random varibles $X_1,....,X_{36}$ are independant and exponentially distributed with $E(X_i)=2$ and $V(X_i)=4$. Pair up the random varibles and the approximative distribution."

I got all of them besides one:

$X_{26}$ and $Exp(0.5)$

I've read through the textbook and I don't understand how this connection is made.
All of the otherpair ups were fairly easy.

What I've got is : $X\in Exp(a), E(X)=a$ and $V(X)=a^2$

I can't connect the dots here, can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: If $a$ is the rate of an exponential distribution then $E(X)=\frac1a$ and $V(X)=\frac1{a^2}$.  You may be mixing up rate and scale

Comment: @Henry thanks! My text book left that part out!